# Why is my Serilog PostgreSQL sink not writing when deployed to AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, serilog, serilog-postgresql

I have a .NET Core API that uses Serilog for logging. When deployed to AWS Lambda, the **Console sink works perfectly and writes all messages to AWS CloudWatch**.

I also have a PostgreSQL sink (Serilog.Sinks.Postgresql.Alternative) which writes to an AWS database. **This works perfectly from my local dev machine. However, when I push it to my AWS Lambda, the database is not getting written to.**

- I'm using the exact same database and connection string.
- I'm using the exact same DB user.
- I can successfully write to the DB from my DAL--apart from logging.

This is in my `Program.Main`.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.PostgreSQL(connectionString, TableName, columnWriters)
    .CreateLogger();
```

What am I missing? Maybe it's not flushing the cache on each HTTP request?

UPDATE: I created a custom .NET Core ILogger, and it has the same behavior. That is, it works locally, but not when deployed to my Lambda.

Comment: Is your database publicly accessible from the internet? Is your Lambda in a VPC?

Comment: My Lambda is in a VPC. My database is not publicly accessible. I'm using a temporary bastion to test it. How would that impact my issue?

Comment: Your Lambda won’t be able to call your database unless you have given it access to connect to your database - have you allowed the Lambda security group (SG) as an allowed inbound connection to the DB?

Comment: Yes, as noted above, I'm already writing to the database from other parts of the app. It's just not working for Logging.

Comment: Yes, you edited the question after I had asked :) thank you, it won’t be what I said then

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how your code is structured, if you have a separate Lambda entry point class, your Program.Main is skipped (it's only called when you run `dotnet run`, thus why it works locally).

You will need to configure the logging in the Lambda entry point class. For example:

```
    public class LambdaEntryPoint : APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyFunction
    {
        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .MinimumLevel.Information()
                 .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                 .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                 .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                 .WriteTo.Console() 
                 .WriteTo.PostgreSQL(connectionString, TableName, columnWriters)
                 .CreateLogger();

            builder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseSerilog();
        }
    }
```

You might find this also doesn't work, the reason being the logs need to be flushed, but you cannot use CloseAndFlush in a lambda, as that closes the stream and there will be no logs on next invocation. Logs to the Console, however, do not need to be flushed.

A solution would be to log to Console, so the logs go to CloudWatch, and then create a Lambda Function triggered by CloudWatch logs for your service, and send them to your PostgreSQL. [Here is an example of a Node.js Lambda function for forwarding logs to Seq](https://gist.github.com/larenelg/326728ada62742dbd128b5ff202c451e).

Hope this helps!